# How can I combine values of checkboxes with values of text in php?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm new with PHP, and I'm making a html form which consist basically in two options: First, the client select a series of checkboxes (parts from an equipment) and then write the amounts of each selected checkbox...

```
<td><input id="11.11.015.0002" name="pecas[]" type="checkbox" value="11.11.015.0002 - BATERIA CHUMBO ACIDO 6V/4AH" /></td>
<td><input name="qntd[]" size="7" type="text" /></td>
```

and in php:

```
if(isset($pecas))
    {
    $mensagem .= "Peças Selecionadas:<br /><br />";
    }
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Selecione as Peças Desejadas!'); location.href='http://www.lyuz.com.br/pecas/erro';</script>";
    exit;
}
    foreach ($pecas as $pecas_s) {
    } $mensagem .= " - ".$pecas_s."<br />";
```

That gave me all the selected checkboxes (parts), now I'm trying to get only the input_text (amounts) associate with these selected checkboxes..

I'm stuck. Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify a key in the name of each element. Use a number and just make sure that `pecas[1]` corresponds to `qntd[1]`. Then when you loop over one of the arrays, the keys will be the same in the other array. For example:

```
<?php
$count = 0;

foreach($itemList as $item){
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "  <td><input type='checkbox' id='{$item['id']}' name='pecas[{$count}]'></td>\n";
    echo "  <td><input type='test' id='{$item['id']}' name='qntd[{$count}]'></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    $count++;
}
```

If there are 3 checkboxes and quantity boxes, and lets say the 1st and 3rd boxes are checked, but not the 2nd. Your post array will look like:

```
array(
    'pecas'=> array(
        0 => 'some value', //notice, no 1 key because the second checkbox was not checked.
        2 => 'some other value'
        ),
    'qntd' => array(
        0 => 'some qntd',
        1 => '' //1 was not checked, so nothing should have been entered in the second textbox.
        2 => 'some other qntd'
        )
    );
```

The keys `0` (first checkbox) and `2` (third) will exist in the 'pecas' array and will correspond with keys `0` and `2` in the 'qntd' array. You can then loop over the data like:

```
//check that at least one checkbox was checked
if(!empty($_POST['pecas'])){
    //loop over the checkboxes getting key ($k) and value ($v).
    foreach($_POST['pecas'] as $k=>$v){
        //display a message
        echo "Pecas {$v} ({$k}) was checked with a qntd of {$_POST['qntd'][$k]}<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I think I get the idea of your suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't know where I can change my code. When you say "Specify a key in the name of each element" I can use "id='{$item['id']}' name='pecas[{$count}]" on my html form? Notice that my form has to be in html only.

Comment: How are you building the form? Using php? or do have the form entirely in an html file? Usually forms like this are built by looping over an array or database result and echo'ing out the form in html.

Comment: My form is an html file, and I can't use another way to build it.

Comment: Well then you would need to go into the html file and update the names of the checkboxes/input boxes manually. This is the simplest way to ensure that the input box and checkbox stay correlated. The only other option would be to just rename all the fields uniquely or use javascript to disable/remove the input box when the checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
foreach ($pecas as $pecas_s) {
   $mensagem .= " - ".$pecas_s."<br />";
}
```

to

```
for($x = 0; $x < count($pecas); ++$x) {
    $mensagem .= " - ".$pecas[$x]. ": " . $qntd[$x] . "<br />"; //Example

}
```

Since it appears that for every $pecas there is a $qntd, so you just need to get the index location of $pecas, and grab that same index location in $qntd

--

Let me add however that checkboxes only get passed IF they are checked, the input boxes will ALWAYS be passed.  So you could have a disparity, where the indexes don't align!  You might want to use some javascript to disable an input box if its checkbox is not selected.

Comment: thanks for so quick answer. I change my code as suggested, but php only returns the selected checkbox, create '$mensagem' but don't get the input value of text. Ex.: - 11.11.015.0002 - BATERIA CHUMBO ACIDO 6V/4AH- Quantidade:

Answer (score 0):

Well, I manage to solve this with help of @Jonathan Kuhn with a little different approach.

In HTML form, I gave indexes in each element,

```
<td><input id="11.11.015.0002" name="pecas[1]" type="checkbox" value="11.11.015.0002 - BATERIA CHUMBO ACIDO 6V/4AH" /></td>
<td><input name="qntd[1]" size="7" type="text" /></td>
```

And in PHP file, I replace

```
foreach ($pecas as $pecas_s) {
   $mensagem .= " - ".$pecas_s."<br />";
}
```

to

```
array('pecas'=> array(), 'qntd' => array());
   if(!empty($_POST['pecas']))
        {
        foreach($_POST['pecas'] as $k=>$v)
            {
                    $mensagem .= "- {$v} - QUANT.: {$_POST['qntd'][$k]}<br>";
            }
}
```

And, finally, my mail returns value of each textbox when the checkbox is checked! \o/