# how combine field (input type=number) with checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox, foreach

**WHAT I HAVE**

I have this table: [TABLE EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElLwH.png)
Whose fields are populated by a mysql database. name of table TABELLA

**HTML**

```
<form action='inserisci.php' method='post'
   <input type='checkbox' name='selected[]' value='{$row['id']}'/>
   <input type='number' min='1' max='99' autocomplete='off' name='quantita[]' value='".substr($row['quantita'],3)."'/>
<input style="width:100px;" type="submit" value="Inserisci"/>
```

**PHP** INCOMPLETE but work without any quantita results

inserisci.php

```
if(!empty($_POST['selected'])) { //Se ci sono spunte
    foreach($_POST['selected'] as $check) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tabella1 (nome, cognome, prodotto) VALUES ('$nome','$cognome', (SELECT prodotto FROM tabella WHERE ID=$check))");
        $query->execute();
```

**WHAT I NEED**

I need to combine selected[] (CHECKBOX) value with quantita[] and insert all in TABELLA1.

I wish also that the values ​​(quantita) from TABELLA to be displayed in field...so that they can be modified (if needed) and be included in the database along with the other values

FOR EXAMPLE (with quantita):

```
("INSERT INTO tabella1 (nome, cognome, prodotto, quantita) VALUES ('$nome','$cognome', (SELECT prodotto FROM tabella WHERE ID=$check), '$quantita')")
```

How i can do that?

Comment: you already posted this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431036/how-to-call-that-variable-in-other-page-foreach and I should have looked at your question(s) before voting to close as "too broad". This is a repost/duplicate post.

Comment: nobody helped me! Now I understand the problem and have been more precise in the description. I'm sorry... i also found 2 similar posts (but I cannot adapt them): [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365425/how-can-i-combine-values-of-checkboxes-with-values-of-text-in-php) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/...ith-html-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved!**

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tabella") as $row) {

    <input type='checkbox' name='seleziona[{$count}]' value='{$row['id']}'/><br /></td><td>
    <input type='number' min='1' max='99' autocomplete='off' name='quantita[{$count}]' id='{$row['id']}' value='".substr($row['quantita'],3)."'/>
            $count++;
}
```

inserisci.php

```
foreach($_POST['seleziona'] as $k=>$v){
        $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tabella1 (nome, cognome, prodotto, quantita) VALUES ('$nome','$cognome', (SELECT prodotto FROM tabella WHERE ID=$v), '{$_POST['quantita'][$k]}')");
        $query->execute();
    }
```